# JavaScript filter() result is always empty inside the callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Task: keep only unique values from an array. Test case:

```
<script>
var ar1 = [1,1];
var ar2 = [];
ar2 = ar1.filter( function( x ) {
    return ( ar2.indexOf(x) < 0 ); // <== always returns true
})
console.log( ar2 ); // <== "Array [ 1, 1 ]" FAIL!
</script>
```

Question: it would appear that the resulting array isn't getting updated while inside the filter() callback. Is this correct? And why? (I'm almost convinced I have a typo in my code which I can't see, because intuitively it *should* work. So I must be misunderstanding filter() by a mile.)

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 if the value isn't found, and since `ar2` is empty when you check, it will always return true. Your code is working as expected.

Comment: The filter method works just like all other functions: it returns the value once after it has finished running completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
var ar1 = [1,1];
var ar2 = [];
var tmp = ar1.filter( function( x ) {
    return ( ar2.indexOf(x) < 0 ); // <== always returns true
})
ar2 = tmp;
```

I wanted to show you that `ar2` is updated with a new value only after `ar1.filter` is finished i.e. after iterating the whole array. So "always return true" is expected behavior.

To solve your task you have to do:

```
var ar1 = [1,1];
var ar2 = [];
for (let x of ar1) {
    if (ar2.indexOf(x) < 0) {
        ar2.push(x);
    }
}
```

So here we are iterating through the array and check if such item is already presented in `ar2`, and push the item at once so `ar2` is always up-to-date on all iterations.

(Warning: ES6 syntax is used in the example)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your code at this line `ar2.indexOf(x) < 0`.

Basically it returns always `true` because `ar2` does not contains `1` since its initialization (as also pointed out @DanielB).

You can use the following code which keep only unique values in an array.

ES6 version:

```js
let ar1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    ar2 = ar1.filter((item, pos) => ar1.indexOf(item) === pos);
console.log(ar2);
```

ES5 version:

```js
var ar1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    ar2 = ar1.filter(function(item, pos) {
        return ar1.indexOf(item) === pos;
    });
console.log(ar2);
```

Comment: Please add a comment when down-voting so I can improve my answer, thanks!

Comment: Not my downvote, but you should still add some explanation as to why this works and the code in the question doesn't.

Comment: @DanielB thanks I appreciate your comment, I have added a brief explanation ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm think that your question is remove duplicated items in the array.using the tmp array instead.because ar2 is always empty before the filter was done.so the callback is always return true.

### Use temporay array instead

```js
var ar1 = [1,5,6,1];
var tmp=[];
var ar2 = ar1.filter( function( x ) {
    return tmp.indexOf(x)<0&&tmp.push(x);
})
console.log( ar2 );
```

### OR Use array reduce instead

```js
var ar1 = [1,5,6,1];
var ar2 = ar1.reduce(function(array,x) {
    if(array.indexOf(x)<0) array.push(x);
    return array;
},[])
console.log( ar2 );
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is correct? The array being returned is `[1,1]` which is a fail according to the OP.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm only copy his data.and not remove the comments.

Comment: The OP wants to remove duplicates from the array. Your answer does the opposite.

Comment: @JJJ yes,he not describe the problem clearly,I know it just now.